# Segwit Addressed from xpub key

Tags: electrum, segregated-witness, xpub

How can i get the public key of my segwit address with my extended public key. when i import the xpub into electrum it automatically creates a legacy wallet for me. i'm not with my nano and won't be with it for a while, please how do i go about it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the xpub into p2wpkh or p2wpkh-p2sh format. You can use [this script](https://github.com/AbdussamadA/electrum-convert-key) to do it.

Comment: I have no idea how i am meant to run that script, can you please guide me?

Comment: see the readme file. you have to run it with the python3 interpreter in a terminal/shell.

Answer (score 0):

You should change derive path to 49 instead of 44. if you are planning to use bech32 addresses then you should make your path 84 but it's not supported yet on electrum.

Comment: Thats the problem it doesn't let me choose the derivation path, it goes straight to creating the wallet when  i put in my xpub key

Comment: you should use the mnemonic phrase to import your wallet because I think they assume the path is 44 for that xPUP

Comment: As i said in my original post, i am not close to my ledger or my seed i just want to monitor my address, please do you know another way?

Comment: if you have your addresses you can add it to electrum as (watch-only) so you watch it.

Comment: I only have the xpub, i thought that was all i needed and when i import into electrum i get the legacy address and i use segwit.